# Some items has black background when using listview with gradient background in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-theme, android-styles

I'm setting a background color for the selected item in listview like this;

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (position == containerFragment.vList.getCheckedItemPosition()) {
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.listview_selected_background);
        } 
        else {
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.listview_default_background);
        }
        return convertView;
}
```

And the color definitions are like this;

```
<color name="listview_default_background">#00000000</color>
<color name="listview_selected_background">#333333</color>
```

If i don't use a gradient everything works fine, but when i use a gradient by "android:windowBackground"; some of the items getting black backgrounds. Any ideas?

Comment: did you try to set `CachHintColor` for `ListView` to transparent?

Comment: @MoshErsan; Yes i did. Thats a strange behaviour. Not all items are black. For example when i select the second item; its background color is set to #333333 which is fine. But when i scroll down; the 9th, 15th, 21st and so on becoming black.

Comment: try to log 
`if (position == containerFragment.vList.getCheckedItemPosition()) {
Log.d(tag,"checkedItem:"+position);`

Comment: if this prints more than one value, then your problem in another location.

Answer (score 0):

If you want solve this problem then use *cacheColorHint* attribute and *@android:color/transparent* value with ListView tag.

**Full Code**

```
<ListView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" />
```